# (Thinkpad) Touchpad flickering issue

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, synaptics

Using Ubuntu 18.04, I've encountered an issue right after installation. It was suddenly gone after a sudo apt-get update/upgrade but reappeared after an update: The (synaptics) touchpad only works for around 1 second, then stops working for 1 second, then works again for 1 second and then doesn't work for another 7 seconds after which the circle starts again. Edit: The issue doesn't appear every time. Sometimes when I start up, the cursor (Touchpad) works fine. This sucks because I have to reserve the seat next to me on trains now, so I can put my mouse on there :)